# Buttons for including Database entries for Express

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

i have a question. How can I creat buttons on my Website which including database entries?
Im using Express, and my database is MySql.

edit: 
Im really sorry, my english and my program skills are not on the highest level but I try my best. If u created a Express app including dic. views, public .... i using the ejs template engine and this is waht i actually have

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h1>You Searched For : <%= data.userQuery %></h1>
          <% if(data.loggedIn){ %>
                <h2> You are logg in as : <%= data.username %> </h2>
            <% } %>
          <ul>
            <% data.searchResults.forEach(result=>{ %>
                <li> <%= result %> </li> 
            <% }); %>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
      </div> 

  <script src="/public/js/example.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

a basic routine as index.ejs

How can I creat a field where I can write and this will add to my database but this field have to be on my Website.
And secound I must creat a button where I can get database entries.

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question that’s difficult to answer concisely and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. Instead of leaving us to speculate on what you might need, give us something to build so we can focus help in those areas where it’s most needed.

Comment: Do you mean you navigating to the database entries page?

Comment: No, /myadmin to login to my database. But I need a button and a textfield which are add or get some database entries on my Website.